# Create a Total Column in a GridView with Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My Gridview has three columns,

First Column:

```
A (header)
1 (values)
2 (values)
3 (values)
```

Second Column:

```
B (header)
2 (values)
4 (values)
6 (values)
```

For the Third Column I need to multiply values from Column A and B and show the result, how do I do that?

Comment: show your efforts and paste code what you have tried

Comment: Which language are you using for this? C# or VB?

Comment: I need a code in C#, my brother...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do calculation in Gridview using inline databinding syntax:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="A" DataField="AValue" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="B" DataField="BValue" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Result">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("AValue")) * Convert.ToInt32(Eval("BValue")))%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Here is the code for binding the grid(Just in case):-

```
private void BindGrid()
        {
            List<Test> testDate = new List<Test>
            {
                new Test { AValue = 1, BValue = 2 },
                new Test { AValue = 2, BValue = 4 },
                new Test { AValue = 3, BValue = 6 }
            };
            grdTest.DataSource = testDate;
            grdTest.DataBind();
        }
```

Where I have used this type:-

```
public class Test
        {
            public int AValue { get; set; }
            public int BValue { get; set; }
        }
```